# Cooler harddisk = faster harddisk?

Tags: 14.04, ati, hard-drive, mate, temperature

So I was using Ubuntu XFCE, now I installed the Ubuntu MATE, and I noticed a slowdown sometimes.

File manager tooks often 3-5 seconds to load
Desktop will rarely freeze for a 2 seconds
Once my browser took 20 seconds to boot...

My HDD temperature is normally 55-65°C laptop. It is 62°C most of the times, dunno why, it should be 55°C. But when I power up room fan on my laptop, it will cool down to 42°C and the system seems to be more responsive. No more long loads of file manager also.

Could this be related? Do harddisks slowdown when hot? I't a laptop, I can't do much to cool it down.

Or does MATE have issues?

Or is it because I switched to 64bit system? In the past I always used 32bit.
I'm not running out of RAM.

Intel Core 2 DUO T5450 1.6GHZ,
ATI Mobility Radeon X2300,
2GB RAM

Comment: You should use 64bit at 3 GB or more of RAM. Also your CPU is very old. I have a CPU with double the GHZ (except that it is 0.04 GHZ worse than 3.2 GHZ), and it is still a Core 2 Duo.

Comment: The reason I installed 64bit was some game that needed it. Also I've seen some benchmarks of 64bit performing better even on old computer. + some advantages like better security.

old CPU for what? MATE?

Comment: You can use it like that, then. My Core 2 Duo is also 64bit.